# Why special characters added when to copy and paste from leafpad into console?

Tags: bash, mouse

There are one character string line in my leafpad.

```
sudo apt-get install ctags
```

When to copy  and paster it with mouse  into command console,`0~` was added at the beginning of the character string line ,and `1~` was added at the end of it,`sudo apt-get install ctags`  turns out to be  `0~sudo apt-get install ctags1~`.
Why and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like **bracketed paste mode** is enabled.
In this case, enter the following command in your terminal to disable it

```
printf "\e[?2004l"
```

If your are interested in this feature, here is a nice introduction:
[bracketed paste mode](https://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste)